# Resolve properties from external file in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, properties-file

My `project/build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
```

My `application.properties` (at the project root):

```
key=value
```

My root `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val projectName = "ai"
name := projectName

val projectVersion = "1.0.0"
version := projectVersion

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= List(
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.11.0-M7",
    "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.10",
    "io.reactivex" % "rxscala_2.11" % "0.25.0",
    "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.2.2",
    "com.jsuereth" %% "scala-arm" % "1.4"
)

val conf = ConfigFactory.load()

assemblyOutputPath in assembly := new  File(s"target/${conf.getString("key")}-$projectVersion.jar")
```

When I run `assembly` in SBT console, I get `[error] (*:assembly::assemblyOutputPath) com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'key'`

Answer (score -1):

Have you put key=value in application.conf?? just define the key inside the application.conf because it search value of key inside application.conf
like example

```
                  key="file_name"
```

Comment: Again, I have `application.properties` containing `key=value`. Renaming it to `application.conf` does not work, too.

Comment: you have only one configuration file or have multiple. can you please copy key=value same as in application.conf.

Comment: once put application.conf into resources folder and then try its work i just do it right now and its works.

Comment: Put it into project/, possibly project/src/main/resources